# PHPTAL and CSV in array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, template-tal, phptal

I have data in CSV format:

> $result->names =
>   array(array('x,y,z'),array('a,b,c'));

for example:

> item.names = 'a,b,c'

this code doesn't work:

```
<div tal:repeat="item result">
<div tal:repeat="x php:explode(',',${item.names})" tal:omit-tag="">
<span tal:content="x"></span>
</div></div>
```

but this code works, why?

```
<div tal:repeat="item result">
<div tal:repeat="x php:explode(',','a,b,c')" tal:omit-tag="">
<span tal:content="x"></span>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `${}` in expressions with `php:` modifier. That should work, assuming you're looping over value from `$result->names`:

```
<tal:block tal:repeat="x php:explode(',', item)">
```

(BTW: instead of `omit-tag` you can use `tal:block` element which is "invisible")